# What is wrong in function

Tags: c++

This Function is supposed to return a letter that has single occurrence, upper cased.

I was trying to find a mistake for 30 minutes and I seriously don't know what is the problem. May someone take a look at this?

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

char singleOccurrence(string str) {
    transform(str.begin(), str.end(), str.begin(), ::toupper);
    sort(str.begin(), str.end());
    for(int i=0; i<str.length(); i++) {
        if(i==str.length()-1)
            return str[i];
        else if(str[i] != str[i+1])
            return str[i];
    }
}

int main()
{
   string str = "ala";
   cout << singleOccurrence(str);
}
```

Comment: Turn on your compiler warnings.

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: "I was trying to find a mistake for 30 minutes and i seriously don't know." What *techniques did you use* to try to find the mistake?

Comment: I'd love to see some statistics on how much time askers claim to have spent finding the issue, 30 minutes is at the lower end btw

Comment: Code compiles, just the return is wrong: it gives 'A' instead of 'L'. transform and sort work

Comment: @roditu *Function is supposed to return a letter that has single occurrence, uppercased* -- FYI --  Did you know that you could do this with a single line of code with no loop using `std::set` or `std::unordered_set`?

Comment: What you should have found in the debugger: `i`: `1`, `str[i]`: `'A'` `str[i + 1]`: `'L'`. Now, take a loot at `if(str[i] != str[i+1]) {return str[i];}`. (Spoiler: `return str[i+1];` doesn't fix it.)

Comment: You are missing a final `else` clause.  Run through the function, verify that all paths are accounted for.  Looks like there are at least 2 cases where the function doesn't return a value.

Comment: The idea with `std::sort()` is not that bad. But, now you have to count equal characters. If the count is 1, you found a candidate for `return`. (Your algorithm is not yet thought up to end.)

Comment: `str[i+1]` has the potential to go out of bounds. That's undefined behaviour.

Comment: By the way, if you know that there is only one letter that occurs an odd number of times and all others occur an even number of times, then you can XOR each element to a running "total".  That total will be that one letter. You'll need to convert to the same case first. The exact details of the problem are sketchy, but this might be an option.

Comment: FYI, you should store `str.length()` into a const temporary variable since the length of the string doesn't change in the `for` loop or anywhere in the function.

Comment: @Bathsheba I agree in general, but isn't it a fact that `str[str.size()]` provides the element with `'\0'` (which is needed for `std::string::c_str()`)? In that special case, it should even work (though I wouldn't rely on this in productive work).

Comment: @Scheff'sCat -- I'm not sure, but I think Visual Studio debug mode flags `str[str.size()]` with an assertion.  At least the older versions did that, not sure of Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: What about the word `bookkeeping`?  What are the expected results?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: Another option is to run the loop backwards but then you're up against it with unsigned arithmetic. (I use the slide operator idiom for that, but that attracts a bad press these days.)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: Since C++11 the NUL terminator needs to be present. Before then it didn't have to be. (Refer to the `.data()`, `.c_str()` changes.)

Comment: @Bathsheba Yes, I know that.  I just checked VS 2019, and it does not give a memory overwrite assertion when accessing the terminating null.  But could still be problematic if the programmer didn't actually intend to access that position, and then sticks a character other than 0 there.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie The behaviour on changing the NUL terminator is undefined.

Answer (score 2):

This if-else statement

```
    if(i==str.length()-1)
    {
      return str[i];
    }
    else
      if(str[i] != str[i+1])
      {
        return str[i];
      }
```

does not make a sense.

For example consider string `s = "aab"`. As `s[1] != s[2]` your function will return the letter `'a'` though it is present in the string more than one time.

Or consider another example of a string like `"aaa"`. In this case your function again will return the letter `'a'`.

If you want to use an approach with a sorted sequence of characters then you could within the function use for example the standard container `std::map<char, size_t>` without sorting the passed string itself.

Otherwise you could use nested for loops for the original string.

In the both cases the function should be declared like

```
char singleOccurrence( const std::string &str );
```

or

```
char singleOccurrence( std::string_view str );
```

If for example in a string there is no such a character you could return the character `'\0'`.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(i==str.length()-1)
    {
      return str[i];
    }
    else
      if(str[i] != str[i+1])
      {
        return str[i];
      } 
  }
```

> After "else" statement you should put and "{", idk if that could be a problem. Second of all that if doesn't return something different, in both cases you return str[i]. Third I don't see iostream library included, don't forget to include  if you want to use cout or cin(for reading from input). Also you call this function once in main and it will always give you the first letter after the letters will be sorted. You can try to use map, which is implemented in STL in map library. In map you can give your letter from that string as a key and key value will be the number of occurrences.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

using namespace std;
// char singleOccurrence(string str)
// {
//   transform(str.begin(), str.end(), str.begin(), ::toupper);
//     sort(str.begin(), str.end());
//       for(int i=0; i<str.length(); i++)
//       {
//         if(i==str.length()-1)
//         {
//           return str[i];
//         }
//         else
//           if(str[i] != str[i+1])
//           {
//             return str[i];
//           } 
//       }
// }


int main()
{
   map<char, int> occurrences;//declare a map, your key will be a char and you key value an int
   string str="ala";
   for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++){
    occurrences[str[i]]++;
   }
   for(auto n : occurrences){
    cout<<n.first<<" "<<n.second<<endl;//n will be an iterator, you use iterators to get map values 
   }//if you want to check the number and show only the letter with a single occurrence just add an if statement and check in key value (n.second) is equal to one
}
```

**I hope this helps! :)**